# Why lamson and sendmail can listen to port 25 the same time?

Tags: sendmail, lamson

I started sendmail at port 25.
Then started lamson (another SMTP server) at port 25.
They both worked.
Why they can listen to the same port?

Answer (score 2):

Only one application can listen once on a port.